# How to count the number of rows inserted in Python?

Tags: python, count

I have a database connection and I insert data into a table using to_sql.

```
xls.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

I've been trying to obtain the number of rows inserted, or the number of rows in the table (considering I truncate the table before inserting new data). I've been unsuccessful though.

Can you help?

I've tried:

```
countRow=engine.execute("select count(*) from "+table);
print(countRow)
```

I find it odd that this doesn't work because I use the same thing to truncate the table. Am I missing something or doing something wrong here?

Comment: Which library you are using ?

Comment: If you're referring to the database connection, I'm using sqlalchemy

Comment: `xls.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)` for `xls`  ?

Comment: xls is just the name for concatenated files

Comment: Can you try with `engine.execute("select count(*) from "+table+ ";").fetchall()` because when you selecting some thing then there are no rows affected?

Answer (score 0):

As @Deepak Tripathi suggested, I used this and it worked:

`engine.execute("select count(*) from "+table+ ";").fetchall()`